Updated Spring Framework from 6.1.8 -> 6.1.12, SPEL expression is not evaluating the same way
After updating springframework 6.1.8 -> 6.1.12, SPEL expresssions look to be evaluating differently
I have an expression that looks like this:
person['title.perms'] ne null and !titles['allowedPerms'].contains(person['title.perms'].trim())

With spring 6.1.8, it'd evaluate to false with person['title.perms'] = 'A' and  title['title.perms'] = ['A', 'B', 'C']. I updated Spring to 6.1.12 and now the expression is true. Why is this?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases/tag/v6.1.12
